# Failed building wheel for scikit-image

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I'm trying to install scikit-image library. As mentioned in official docs I'm running the command:

```
python -m pip install -U scikit-image
```

What I have already:

1. I have a virtual environment created for my project named env
2. I have numpy installed in my virtualenv
3. Python version 3.11.1

I'm attaching logs which I think should be relevant for diagnosing the error.

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for scikit-image (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [760 lines of output]
      setup.py:9: DeprecationWarning:

        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html


        from numpy.distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext as npy_build_ext
      C:\Users\apoor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-nxyulh5k\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pythran\tables.py:4555: FutureWarning: In the future `np.bytes` will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.  (This may have returned Python scalars in past versions.
        obj = getattr(themodule, elem)
      Partial import of skimage during the build process.


There are a lot of logs between these two sections!

 INFO: No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      INFO: customize MSVCCompiler
      INFO: customize MSVCCompiler using ConditionalOpenMP

A lot more logs...


      CPU baseline  :
        Requested   : 'min'
        Enabled     : SSE SSE2 SSE3
        Flags       : none        Extra checks: none
      CPU dispatch  :        Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'        Enabled     : SSSE3 SSE41 POPCNT SSE42 AVX F16C FMA3 AVX2 AVX512F AVX512CD AVX512_SKX AVX512_CLX AVX512_CNL AVX512_ICL        Generated   : none
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image
Failed to build scikit-image
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Python 38 seems to solve the installation problem